# position estimation using imu

Tags: imu, path, dead-reckoning

I have an Inertial Navigation System (INS) that publishes position information in GPS and UTM formats. I have mounted the device on a robot. My objective is to move the robot from location A to location B and assess the accuracy of the INS in providing position information. I intend to input the initial position of the cart to the INS, move the robot precisely 20 meters, and then record the new position.
Do you have any specific guidance for doing this test?

Comment: You are mentioning two completely different topics, and it's unclear what you are asking about. Please edit your question (and title) to focus on a single question.

Comment: You're not giving us much information to go on. You don't tell us manufacturer/model, or even say what environment this device is designed for e.g. plane or car or submarine. There's a chance it won't work at all without a GPS signal input.

Answer (score 0):

Given you mention inertial + camera in your initial question: I suggest to have a look at this [ROS Discourse thread](https://discourse.ros.org/t/setting-up-vio-vslam-with-nav2/34005) and corresponding [Nav2 documentation page](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/integrating_vio.html) on Visual Inertial Odometry (VIO).

If this is not what you are looking for, then you need to specify your question and the context of your application more clearly.

Comment: The OP opened a new question for the camera part: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104873/improving-ins-positon-estimation-using-camera

Comment: Uh never mind... I see that question got closed as an unbounded design question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the robot_localization's implementation of the extended kalman filter to fuse all of the odometry data you have between camera, GPS, and IMU. This will give you the robot's relative position from it's starting point and you can literally send a move_base goal 20m ahead of it and manually check it's accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend relying on visual or lidar odometry due to their inherent drift issues. Instead, I suggest employing Aruco markers. Create a large sheet with various Aruco markers of different sizes, ensuring they are visible at varying distances. By accurately estimating the robot's position relative to one of these markers, you can validate your data.